# easy way to rem android studio shortcuts

Tags: android-studio

Is there away make thing faster so I don't have a hard time rem android studio shortcuts?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'rem'? Please edit your post for clarity and describe what you want to achieve in more detail.

Comment: I mean it hard to remember all the shortcuts.

Comment: Just try to use them in your working time ....

Comment: Not many people know this, but you can close the current project and open Intellij IDEA Welcome Screen. On the left pane click on Learn IntelliJ IDEA -> Interactive Course / Learn IDE Features: Start Learning. It's an awesome set of tutorials for the best shortcuts.
You can also install this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1003-key-promoter
It remembers you to use shortcuts and has nice statistics.

Comment: Thank you didn't know there a plugin help with Shortcuts.Does this work on the macOS to?